# React Component: Declaration or statement expected ts(1128)

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I am pretty new to React and run into some trouble regarding syntax quiet often.
The following Code gives me error: Declaration or statement expected ts(1128)

Scanning the internet I came to the conclusion that it is most likely some bracket missing?!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AuthContext from './AuthContext';

// Then create a provider Component to update children Components once the user role changes
class AuthProvider extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
          role: "none"
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,
        isAuthenticated: () => {
          if (this.state.role == "kursleiter" || this.state.role == "admin") {
            return true
          }
          return false},
        setRole: (newRole) => this.setState({
            role: newRole
        })
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default AuthProvider
```

Comment: that seems fine, any other clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Super stupid on my site: The filename didn't match, that was all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the code into a function and so that you can call them. Example:

```
const isAuthenticated = () => {
 // ...
}
```

Now, you can use:

```
value={{
  state: this.state,
  isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated()
```

Beforehand, you were using function but not it's call. So, react was throwing you error for statement expected.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fix it for me sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by renaming the exact component file. So maybe i had projects.jsx then changed to project.jsx. The amazing thing is when i switched back to my original file name (projects.jsx) the error didn't occur again.

Comment: the magic of TypeScript